# How to create a new application version in AWS Elastic Beanstalk and deploy it to the existing application/environment using Cloud Formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have an existing Elastic Beanstalk application "app-ebs" and environment "App-ebs-env". I want to create a new application version in elastic beanstalk and deploy the newly created version using cloud formation(I do it manually for now).

The below code works for creating the new application version.(Only for the first time. If I  try to update the stack and try the same template again, it does not work because there's no change set.)

```
Resources:
  myAppVersion: 
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties: 
      ApplicationName: app-ebs    
      SourceBundle: 
        S3Bucket: my-bucket-name
        S3Key: sample.war
```

If I use AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment, I get error because the environment already exists. I do not want to create a new environment.

```
Resources:
  myAppVersion: 
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties: 
      ApplicationName: app-ebs    
      SourceBundle: 
        S3Bucket: my-bucket-name
        S3Key: sample.war
  myEnvironment:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: app-ebs
      EnvironmentName: App-ebs-env
      VersionLabel: !Ref myAppVersion  # Reference the application version created above
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.3.12 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 8
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: " I get error" - what error? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: The error says "Environment App-ebs-env already exists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) your `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` into CloudFormation first, before you can modify it from CloudFormation.

You have to do it for all resources that you created manually, and which you want to manage now using CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But as per "Resources supported by import" section in the given ink, `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment` is not supported whereas `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application` is supported. Does that mean I would not be able to implement what I'm trying?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html

Comment: @Chuck Then, you have to tear down your current EB and create it from scratch using CloudFormation.